# Making a generic enclosing class for deserialized json data?

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I am using a rest api which grants access to a number of collections. These collections coorespond to tables in a database. Queries return data like so:

```
{
"CollectionName_list": [
        // The stuff I actually care about
                 ],
"returned": 105 // Number of items in result list
}
```

I can use `JsonConvert` to correctly parse everything if I make a different enclosing class for *every single collection* in addition to a class for the objects in each collection.

I don't see the point of making ~100 classes with only two attributes to enclose the classes that I actually care about. How can I make a single generic class to represent the results of any query?

Comment: Why do you need so many classes? Not very clear how your classes are organized, but possibly one generic type should be enough...

Comment: How would I make a generic type though? The actual list of results has a different name depending on the collection that was queried.

Comment: I see what you mean "CollectionName_list" now... Maybe some custom serialization could help.